# Change the app language programmatically - UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, multilingual

I have created resource files (`.resw`) for French and English. Now I want to call resource file for "fr" on loading the first page of my app. I have done like below. But it shows an exception

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object".

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="txt_launch3" Grid.Row="4"  Padding="7"/>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {    
       this.InitializeComponent();
       string getDeviceDefaultLang="fr";
       ChangeLanguage2(getDeviceDefaultLang);    
    }

    private void ChangeLanguage2(string language)
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride =language;
            Frame.CacheSize = 0;
         Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();          Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
            Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exx = ex.ToString(); //getting System.NullReferenceException            
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: On which line does the exception happen? Which object is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the method too early within the page. In the constructor the page is not yet assigned to the `Frame` it resides in. Because of this the `Frame` is still `null` there.

You could move the method call to the `OnNavigatedTo` override:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string getDeviceDefaultLang = "fr";
    ChangeLanguage2(getDeviceDefaultLang);
}

private void ChangeLanguage2(string language)
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = language;
        Frame.CacheSize = 0;
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
        Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string exx = ex.ToString(); //getting System.NullReferenceException            
    }
}
```

Alernatively you could directly access the root frame of the app instead of through the `Frame` property of the page:

```
private void ChangeLanguage2(string language)
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = language;
        var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame.CacheSize = 0;
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
        rootFrame.Navigate(this.GetType());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string exx = ex.ToString(); //getting System.NullReferenceException            
    }
}
```

However, this is really not optimal, because you are essentially navigating while there is an navigation currently taking place (the original `MainPage` navigation.

Most likely you will call the change language in response to user action anyway (like button click), when none of this will be a problem anymore and `Frame` will be defined.

### Update

The best solution would be to set the language override in the `OnLaunched` handler in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
    {
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "fr";
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();

            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: now not showing any exception. But language is not changing.  is rootFrame.CacheSize = 0; causes the issue?

Comment: Can you please try to execute the method after a button click to see if it works then?

Comment: But my  purpose is different. when launch the app first time I want to display texts in system's default language.

Comment: The problem is that when you call `Navigate` in the constructor, the "newly" created page will be shown first and then it will get covered by the old page, which does not contain the updated language. You really need to move the code to `OnNavigatedTo` at least, or call it from the end of `OnLaunched` in `App.xaml.cs`. Furthermore, if you want to show texts in the system language, you shouldn't have to do anything, system language is the default, you use `PrimaryLanguageOverride` to use a different language than the system default.

Comment: I was treied with onNaviagted as in your code.  PrimaryLanguageOverrid is used because there is a chance for app may not have the resource file for the language that the default language of system have.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of how to apply the language before the first navigation, hence frame cache edit is not even necessary